# Crashing video camera in CyanogenMod 7.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-one, camera, video-recording

I just updated CyanogenMod 7 to 7.2 on my *Nexus One*. Now when I go to *camera → photo mode* it works well, but if I switch to video mode it just crashes.

I tried to find an answer on the CyanogenMod site, but as much as I searched I found no matching question. As far as I could see on the CyanogenMod site, the latest stable version for the *Nexus One* is 7.2. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Try this: Settings >> Applications >> Camera >> Clear Data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please erase the camera data:

```
Settings -> Application -> Camera -> Clear Data
```